# iOS Swift: Static Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My table has 3 section, each section has a cell, one cell contains an ImageView and two of them contain a label.

Should I make 3 different CellController to populate them or there is a faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only three rows, you can simply create them as static cells on your storyboard and then link to the value fields in the rows directly from your view controller via outlets. That way you don't have to do any cell handling at all except from your view controller.

This works for simple tables. If you have something more complicated, then you might want to go a different way :)

Comment: thank you, but doing that how can I use the reload table function?

Comment: Rather than reloading the table you'd simply set the values directly since you have all the rows displaying all the time and have access to the cell fields directly :)

Comment: but i get the values from an API, it's async

Comment: Since you are connecting directly to the static cell fields, you'd have an outlet for each field in your view controller. So it works basically the same as if you connected to a text field or a label. Once your data is fetched from the API, you just assign the values directly to each cell value. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way I believe it is to use static cells. But you should understand that it is not so flexible way and should be used if you now that no dynamic UI changes are required. You should have 1 cell type. It is for the image one. Label cells are default one that could be used.

Small example:

[image]